# How do I increase the traceLength for a failed test in Codeception?

Tags: codeception

If a test fails and Codeception was run with --debug the last 6 executed steps are displayed. Starting with the headline "Scenario Steps".

As far as I can see this number is defined in: `src/Codeception/Subscriber/Console.php` `protected $traceLength = 5;`. Is there any way to increase the number to show more steps?

We extracted some commonly used functionality to Tester classes which leads to some cases where only steps from that Tester class are shown making it harder to find out where in the test this error occurred.

Comment: No, there isn't. Please raise an issue in Github: https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/